# Value getting lost in hierarchical ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, hierarchy

for my compsci project I'm creating a gui calendar which is supposed to store different information for every date of month of year. This is my code of achieving this hierarchical relationship. yy and mm are public static ArrayLists.

```
//Populating yy arraylist
    for (int i = 0; i<52; i++)
    {
        Year y = new Year();
        y.setYear(1968+i);
        for (int n = 0; n<12;n++)
        {
            Month m = new Month();
            DateCal[] dd = new DateCal[31];
            m.setMonth(n+1);
            for(int c = 0; c<31;c++)
            {
                dd[c] = new DateCal();
                dd[c].setDd(c+1);
                dd[c].setMm(n+1);
                dd[c].setYy(1968+i);
            }
            m.setDate(dd);
            mm.add(m);
        }   
        y.setMonth(mm);
        yy.add(y);
    }
```

After populating the arraylist, I need to be able to get the year of a selected date by accessing layer by layer as such:

```
yy.get(50).getMonth().get(3).getDate()[5].getYy()
```

The problem is that when I add Month m into mm, dd contains the correct year values. However, after the line mm.add(m), every year value for any date is set to 1968. So if I did `mm.get(2).date[3].getYy()`inside the for loop, then it would get the correct year value, but not after I add y to yy and do getYy() on a date; the dates just lose the assigned year value.

I've tried using constructors for month and year, making y and m public static, and everything I could. I have been stuck on this for days. I just can't figure out why this won't store values correctly. The problem arises from this part of my code and only here; there are no errors inside the Month or Year or DateCal classes. I promise. I would very much appreciate if anyone could take a look! I am desperate! :))

Comment: Use `Java`'s `LocalDate`. It can store all that info for you. `List<LocalDate> dateCal = new ArrayList();`.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/CalendarFx/tree/master/src/calendarfx

Comment: @Sedrick, maybe that's not the point of the school project

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's possible that you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem as I see it is that you have two static arrays, `yy` and `mm`. First of all it makes no sense to have a global variable for months when you already have that information within the global variable for years, just more data and code to maintain.

Secondly here is where I spot a bug in your code

```
y.setMonth(mm);
```

´
Here you assign the static array to the year instance meaning all `Year` object will share the same `Month` array object.

I would start by killing the `mm` array and instead let Year have an internal array of (12) Month objects. So maybe change `setMonth` to `addMonth`

One more minor thing to avoid bugs, when you do

```
y.setYear(1968+i);
```

then later when you want to set the same value again you shouldn't do `dd[c].setYy(1968+i)`but instead `dd[c].setYy(y.getYear())` and similar for other values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Although I am not quite sure as to why all Year object will share the same Month array object if the mm arraylist contains 12 different Month objects.

Comment: Because `mm` is static so there is only one instance of it. So `y` for 1986 will use the same `mm` instance as any other year like `y` for 1989 or 1974 or... Avoid using static variables as much as possible, they are bad code design.